# Matching same item in Mongo Array using $all

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am writing a simple blackjack program.  In Blackjack, folks should split their hand when they have a pair of Ace's or Eights (among other times).

I store all possible hand combinations in unique documents in Mongo. Each possible hand for a player is stored with a possible dealer up card and the associated action when following "Blackjack Basic Strategy".  For example:

```
  { "playerHand": [8,8], "upcard" : 10, "action" : "Split" }
  { "playerHand": ["A","A"], "upcard" : 6, "action" : "Split" }
```

To evaluate a person's hand to decide what do to, I grab their hand, stored as an array, (example, ["A", "A"] or [8,8]) and pass it to my Mongo query.

Here is the query:

```
strategy = "Basic Strategy"
playerHand = Players.findOne({_id: playerId}).currentHandCards
doc = Strategy.findOne({ $and: [ {name: strategy}, {"playerHand.cards" : { $all: playerHand} }, {"playerHand.situation.upcard" : dealerUpcard} ]})
doc.playerHand.situation.action
```

This approach works great for all possible hands, but seems to fail when the player has a pair of the same card. I think I must be missing something about how $all treats duplicates.

Thanks for any insight!

---

The collection is created using this insert command.

```
  Strategy.insert
    name: "Basic Strategy"
    playerHand:
      cards: playerHand
      situation:
        upcard: upcard
        action: action
```

Comment: Can you please post your sample collection and ouput

Comment: Hi @Ashish, I added the insert command to show the structure.  Every hand variant of the player and dealer get their own unique document in the collection. When I run the program, I end up getting output, but it is incorrect (ie. "Hit" vs. "Split").  So I don't get an error.  The query finds a result it likes.

Comment: What I need here is your **sample collection** and **sample output** and some explanation nothing else